# What is the facebook PHP sdk equivalent to FB.getLoginStatus?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

What is the PHP equivalent to Facebook's JS SDK of:

```
FB.getLoginStatus
```

I'm looking for something like:

```
$facebook->getLoginStatus()
```

However the above does not exist in the PHP library.

I have already tried both of these:

```
$this->facebook->api('/me');
$this->facebook->getUser();
```

Both do not work because PHP errors out, saying that I need a valid access_token and I am left with a blank page. I am unable to even check for a null response for the 2 methods above.

I simply need to check if a user is a returning user or not. Please help!

Comment: As long as you don't have valid access token - user is not logged in for your application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

To check if the user is logged in on facebook (similar to FB.getLoginStatus) you need to do:

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
else {
  $fbUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => '........'));
  header("Location:".$fbUrl);
  exit();
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: error: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.

Comment: with this work if the user is coming back after 5 months? are there any access_token issues with that?

Comment: user can be logged out and you can be caching the token thus the /me returns valid data

Comment: This doesn't work for me at all - still showing user logged in